# Smart cast is impossible

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I am trying to integrate UMP platform based on this documentation but I receive the following error. Could someone give me a suggestion on how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

[The bug is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HNg3.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `consentInformation` as a nullable field in line 14:

```
private var consentInformation: ConsentInformation? = null
```

As the field is mutable, its value could have changed between the execution of line 23 and line 24, so the compiler disallows you to refer to it without a null check.

In this specific case you could just change the field to be `lateinit` as you're assigning it in the `onCreate` method, which is executed first.

```
private lateinit var consentInformation: ConsentInformation
```

For more information about null safety in kotlin [check this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).